# Установка Microsoft Office 2010 Government OPEN на Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server, office

Здравствуйте!Ситуация следующая...имеется рабочая лошадка на Windows Server 2008 R2. К ней через RDP подключаются пользователи (лицензии установлены).  На сервер установили Microsoft Office 2010 Home&Business - поняли, что сделали глупость (выходит предупреждение: "Эту копию Office 2010 нельзя использовать на компьютере, выполняющем службы терминалов...").

Заказали Microsoft Office 2010 Russian Government OPEN 1 License Level C и Microsoft Win Rmt Dsktp Svcs CAL 2012 Russian Government OPEN 1 License Level C User CAL.Пришло 2 таких бело-синих конверта - Microsoft Open License (Volume Licensing). Вскрыли - тут всякие номера лицензиата, номера лицензии и много всякой писанины (диска, естественно, нет).

В связи с этим вопрос - можете объяснить по-русски, как сделать следующие вещи:

1. установить этот Office 2010 Government, где брать дистрибутив, как его активировать?
2. каким образом ставятся эти Rmt Dsktp Svcs CAL-лицензии?
3. Элемент списка

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте зарегистрироваться в [Центре поддержки корпоративных лицензий Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/Licensing/servicecenter/default.aspx), если меня не подводит память, там можно скачать дистрибутивы.
По второму вопросу - Вы купили клиентские лицензии CAL служб удаленных рабочих столов Windows Server 2012, насколько я понял. Если у Вас уже есть сервер териминалов с лицензиями, то, мне кажется, что эти могут Вам и не пригодиться. Может и ошибаюсь.